# Clean code, how to improve a class

Tags: java, code-cleanup

I've got my `CommandFormatValidator` class, which checks if entered string fits into any of predefined patterns. With a time the class was implementing more and more new patterns, what has led to the following form of the class:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class CommandFormatValidator {

    private Pattern adlPatternAll = Pattern
            .compile("^ACTV/(READ|ADD|DEL|RPL)/ADL.*");

    private Pattern adlPatternAddDefault = Pattern
            .compile("^ACTV/ADD/ADL/(DFLTTY((/([A-Z0-9]{7})){1,5})|DFLMIN(/[0-9]{1,4}))");

    private Pattern adlPatternDeleteTtymailGeneral = Pattern
            .compile("^ACTV/(DEL|READ)/ADL/TTYMAIL(/[A-Z0-9]{7})?");

//around 20 more pattern declarations...

public void validate(Object payload){

        String command = (String)payload;

        if (adlPatternAll.matcher(command).matches()) {
            if (!adlPatternAddDefault.matcher(command).matches()) {
                if (!adlPatternAddCityTty.matcher(command).matches()) {
                    if (!adlPatternAddCityFltTty.matcher(command).matches()) {
                        if (!adlPatternAdd.matcher(command).matches()) {
                            if (!adlPatternDelDefault.matcher(command).matches()) {
                                if (!adlPatternDel.matcher(command).matches()) {
                                    if (!adlPatternDelCityFltTty.matcher(command).matches()) {
                                        if (!adlPatternRpl.matcher(command).matches()) {
                                            if (!adlPatternRead.matcher(command).matches()) {
                                                if (!adlPatternReadCityFlt.matcher(command).matches()) {
                                                    if(!adlPatternAddTtymail.matcher(command).matches()) {
                                                        if( !adlPatternDeleteTtymailGeneral.matcher(command).matches()) {
                                                            if (!adlPatternDeleteTtymail.matcher(command).matches()) {
                                                                throw new ServiceException(CommandErrors.INVALID_FORMAT);
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Right now I would like to clean up this class. Does anybody has any idea how could I achieve that? I would be especially thankful for any design pattern which I could apply for my case.

Comment: Why don't you use `&&` instead of nested if-conditions?

Comment: If each of your `Pattern` instance stands for some sort of specific pattern, then just subclass from `Pattern` class to create your own pattern, and define behavior for each of your pattern by overriding abstract methods, such as the behavior when it matches. Then you just need to put all your pattern instances into an array or list, and try to match the pattern and invoke the behavior on the string to match.

Comment: @KeqiangLi Subclass `Pattern`?!? Yikes. Well, you can't anyway. It's `final`.

Comment: @Andreas Alright, weren't aware of that. Thanks. Then still can define a customized class with a pattern and a lambda function to deal with what needs to be handled when the pattern of it matches the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could list them all in an array, and iterate the array.

BTW: You don't need the `^` anchor when using `matches()`.

Don't know if you missed the `!` on the first test, but here it is without:

```
public class CommandFormatValidator {

    private Pattern adlPatternAll = Pattern
            .compile("^ACTV/(READ|ADD|DEL|RPL)/ADL.*");

    private Pattern adlPatternAddDefault = Pattern
            .compile("^ACTV/ADD/ADL/(DFLTTY((/([A-Z0-9]{7})){1,5})|DFLMIN(/[0-9]{1,4}))");

    private Pattern adlPatternDeleteTtymailGeneral = Pattern
            .compile("^ACTV/(DEL|READ)/ADL/TTYMAIL(/[A-Z0-9]{7})?");

    //around 20 more pattern declarations...

    private Pattern[] adlAll = { adlPatternAddDefault
                               , adlPatternDeleteTtymailGeneral
                               //more
                               };

    public void validate(Object payload){
        String command = (String)payload;
        if (! adlPatternAll.matcher(command).matches())
            return;
        for (Pattern p : adlAll)
            if (p.matcher(command).matches())
                return;
        throw new ServiceException(CommandErrors.INVALID_FORMAT);
    }
}
```